# launching java program via batch and php,

Tags: java, php, windows, batch-file, cmd

php and batch files.

So i'm executing batch files through php

I have no issues launching the batch.

```
        $str = exec('C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\MInecraft\_restart.bat');
```

However the issue im having is getting the batch file to work currectly. When the batch is run, it executes this code

```
    taskkill /IM java.exe /F
    java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
```

batch file successfully runs the taskkill command when launched with php, however it will not run the next line. When ran manually it launches fine, (bear in mind that the cmd.exe does not exit it stays open with this code)

Any ideas on how i can get this to launch from php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to post back here, I specified java through windows path command rather than the batch. The problem is because the java process takes the cmd and turns it into a console, it never finishes the batch file. So, the php never returns and continues the code unless the batch is force ably closed on the server.

```
pclose(popen("start /B C:\MInecraft\_restart.bat &", "r")); die();
```

I ended up using this command, which i believe makes it launch the batch and not wait for a reply. Just carry on with the php.

Thanks for your kind reply. I did initially try launching java in multiple ways.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is the same as given at [Error Executing Batch file of BlazeDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424665/error-executing-batch-file-of-blazeds/24440273#24440273), the java executable is not found by Windows on running the batch file from within PHP script.

The current working directory or the directories listed in environment variable **PATH** can be different when the batch file is executed from within the PHP script in comparison to running the batch file manually.

Do you have ever tried to specify `java.exe` with full path in double quotes in the batch file?

You could also add at top of the batch file the commands

```
dir /w
PATH
```

to see which directory is the current directory and which directories are listed in environment variable **PATH** on execution of the batch file from within PHP script.