# Error Executing Batch file of BlazeDS

Tags: batch-file, jar, file-permissions, blazeds, windows-firewall

I'm trying to see samples of BlazeDs in my web brower as shown in the tutorial on this webpage.

[image: tutorial]

After I have started tomcat i open the localhost link 8400/samples in my browser as shown below.After entering the url i get the following page in my browser..

[image: BlazeDs Sample]

After that i try to start the sample database according to the instructions given in a box at the starting of the webpage. After i run the specified command on my command prompt i get the following error message..
[image: Prompt]

I can't seem to understand the error.Even though i have set the JAVA_HOME variable as follows still i am getting this error..

[image: JAVA_HOME]

Is this error due to firewall problem? or something else??

Please Help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*java* is not an internal command of **cmd.exe**.

As this command is without file extension and without full path, Windows searches first in current directory `C:\blazeds\sampledb` for `java.*` to find either `java.com`, `java.exe`, `java.bat`, `java.cmd` and some other file extensions.

The file extensions are defined in environment variable **PATHEXT** separated by semicolons which can be viewed in a command prompt window with command `set PATHEXT`

If there is no such file with file name `java` in current directory, Windows searches in all directories specified separated by semicolons in environment variable **PATH**. Entering just `path` or `set path` in a command prompt window results in a display of those directories. (`set path` lists the directories of **PATH** and the file extensions of **PATHEXT** as both environment variables start with the string "path".)

The environment variable **JAVA_HOME** is needed perhaps by the Java package itself and other applications, but is definitely not read by Windows to find an executable file with name **java**.

Search for the directory containing **java.exe** and append the directory of this file to PATH. On command line this can be done with:

```
PATH=%PATH%;Full path to directory containing java
```

Do not enter double quotes even if the full path to directory containing java.exe contains 1 or more space characters.

Or you run the java application with the command line

```
"Full path to directory\java.exe" -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server
```